# How to disable debug optimization in eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse

I want to stop debug optimization in eclipse cdt  and I read article about this

http://husks.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/hardware-debugging-the-arduino-using-eclipse-and-the-avr-dragon/

it supposed to see tool setting in eclipse indigo but I didn't see it.

what is the problem

see this for more info

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/forums/forum/5471/topic/5170910

this is my make file

```
TOP=../../..
DIRNAME=src/programs/init_gau
BUILD_DIRS = 
ALL_DIRS= $(BUILD_DIRS)
SRCS = \
  accum.c \
  init_gau.c \
  main.c \
  parse_cmd_ln.c
H = \
  accum.h \
  init_gau.h \
  mk_sseq.h \
  parse_cmd_ln.h


FILES = Makefile $(SRCS) $(H)
TARGET = init_gau

ALL = $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

include $(TOP)/config/common_make_rules
```

I found this config file

```
# -*- makefile -*-
#
# This file is automatically generated by configure.
# Do not hand edit.

CC       = gcc
CFLAGS   = -g -O0 -Wall -fPIC -DPIC
CPPFLAGS = -I/media/sda5/sphinx/tutorial/SphinxTrain/../sphinxbase/include -I/media/sda5/sphinx/tutorial/SphinxTrain/../sphinxbase/include 
DEFS     = -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"SphinxTrain\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"sphinxtrain\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0.99\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"SphinxTrain\ 1.0.99\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBM=1
LIBS     = -lm  -lsphinxbase
LDFLAGS  =  -L/media/sda5/sphinx/tutorial/SphinxTrain/../sphinxbase/src/libsphinxad           -L/media/sda5/sphinx/tutorial/SphinxTrain/../sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase           -L/media/sda5/sphinx/tutorial/SphinxTrain/../sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/.libs

AR       = ar
RANLIB   = ranlib

FESTIVAL = /usr/bin/festival
PERL     = /usr/bin/perl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are under project properties as explained in first tutorial. If you are trying to build a project with existing makefile, then you need to edit the makefile. 
You dont typiclly need to change project properties. Debug configuration builds without optimization by default. You just need to make sure you jave it selected. This is done using the icon (sundial? - the one next to CDT's build (hammer)).

Comment: How to disable optimisation in c++ make file to use it with eclipse cdt

Comment: This seems like a part of larger makefile. Somewhere in it (common_make_rules) you will find compiler switches. Often there is special variable for this (like CFLAGS or CPPFLAGS). If not, switches will be listed somewhere near compiler command. For gcc, you need to place -O0 there (replacing other -O if it's there)